# Performance critical: a service for each task or a single service that handles all the different tasks?

Tags: java, android, performance, service

I want to solicit a general discussion about architecture regarding the use of `Service`.
Please consider that for the app I am writing performance is critical, especially memory consumption.

Let's say you have different types of tasks. What I did is create a Service for each task with its own notification.
Because tasks cannot run simultaneously, when starting a service, if there is still another service of my app alive I need to stop it.
However I am not sure performance wise how great this approach is.

The other approach would be to have one single service that basically handles the different tasks depending on the user selection, like a Spinner.
Personally what would you choose and why? Thanks.